# Let $A\subset \Bbb R$ be a set, such that for each open cover of $A$, there exists a finite sub-cover of $A$. Prove that $A$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

**Exercise.** Let $A\subset  \Bbb R$ be a set, such that for each open cover of $A$, there exists a finite sub-cover of $A$. Prove that $A$ is bounded.

**Attempt.** Suppose, on the contrary, that $A$ is unbounded (w.l.o.g assume it is only bounded from below). Let $C$ be an open cover of $A$. Then, it contains a finite sub-cover $C_0$ of $A$. $C_0$ is a limited collection of intervals; thus, we conclude that $\sup C_0$ is a finite number $S$. Since $A$ is not bounded from above, an $x \in A$ can always be found so that $x>\sup C_0$. A contradiction to the existence of a finite cover.

Is my solution correct?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Context! Is $A$ a subset of a metric space? Or some other topological space? Otherwise, “open cover” has no meaning

Comment: However, judging by your language, I presume $A\subset\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean topology

Comment: $\sup C_0$ does not make sense. $C_0$ is a set of open sets. $\sup S$ only makes sense when $S$ is (in this context) a set of real numbers.

Comment: @FShrike My question is about $A \subset \Bbb R$. I have edited it.

Comment: You seem to believe that an unbounded set cannot be covered by a finite union of open sets. This is wrong. Even a single open set suffices: the whole space itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have a metric, otherwise unbounded makes no sense. If $A$ is empty then we are done because for all $x\in A$, it is vacuously true that they are separated by a distance of no more than one.

If $A\ne\emptyset$, let $a\in A$ be given and let $B_n(a)$ be the open ball of radius $n$ around $a$. Then, $\{B_i(a)\}$, for $i\in\mathbb N$ forms an open cover of $A$. Since it has a finite subcover, there exists a maximum $m$ such that all of $A$ is contained in $B_m(a)$.

Therefore, $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this answer generalises the case when $A$ is a sub-set of $\Bbb R$, and instead of an open ball, we have a collection of open intervals $I_n(a)$, whose endpoints are situated at a distance $n$ from some given $a\in A$?

Comment: @LordMansfield This generalizes to any metric space. In $\mathbb R$ the open balls will be open intervals. Under other metrics, the open ball may actually look like an open cube.